# Como salvar o caminho de uma imagem no momento da criação de uma tabela no SQL?

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados

Olá, pessoal tudo bem?
Tenho seguinte caso: preciso criar uma tabela produto com os atributos 'id', 'descricao', 'estoque', 'unidade', 'preco' e 'local_photo', só que tenho dúvidas quanto ao tipo de dado para salvar o caminho dessa foto. Seria um varchar suportando quantos caracteres?

```
CREATE TABLE produto (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    descricao VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    estoque INT (40) NOT NULL,
    preco_venda FLOAT NOT NULL,
    unidade CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    local_photo ??
    
    


);
```

Comment: é melhor guardar o caminho da imagem, e o tamanho do `varchar` irá depender de onde ela ficará guardada e do tamanho do nome da imagem.

Comment: Um varchar de (100) será que tá bom?

Comment: já pesquisou o tamanho máximo path que o SO onde a imagem vai estar hospedada suporta? a maioria dos sistemas operacionais tem algo em torno de 255, mas é preciso confirmar, mas no fundo você quem está desenvolvendo é que precisa saber isso. Onde as imagens vão ser armazendas? qual o path? como é `varchar`pode colocar um tamanho maior que esperado que não vai usar, mas o problema é mesmo saber como isso vai ser armazenado, descubra isso e vai ter sua resposta :)

Comment: as imagens podem tanto ter um nome como `teste.png` como também `teste-implantado-na-empresa-fulana-20-19-2020-11-24-30.png`, ainda tendo que adicionar o caminho completo de onde ela está guardada. tudo depende de como está estruturado o seu servidor.

Comment: Varchar foi criado para isto , você cria com um tamanho "bom o suficiente" e ele só usa o que precisar, sua reposta depende ...

Comment: O tamanho máximo que um nome de arquivo pode ter depende do sistema operacional e de sua versão, e do sistema de arquivos utilizados.